# How can I have Cortana tell me what song is playing? (on my phone; not in background; by using it's metadata)

Tags: 8.1, music, cortana

I have Cortana speech assistant set up on my Windows 8.1 phone. It is a Microsoft Lumia 535.

I have many song files stored on my phone. They are ripped from my CD collection as MP3 files, and tagged with Artist, Album, Song, etc.

When I am playing the song on my phone, I want to be able to ask it, "What song is this?". I do this by holding the search button and then saying that phrase out loud.

It then shows "Listening for music...", and identifies the song by "listening" to it and searching for it on the internet.

How can I have it just tell me out loud what the song name is by using the metadata / id tags? What are some exact phrases to use?

To clarify, a data or WiFi connection should not be necessary...just for it to read the MP3 metadata and say what the song is.

It's kind of a mystery so please help me to figure the wording out. I know I've done it before but don't know how exactly!

EDIT:

I would like to encourage people to post some examples of voice commands that do or don't work.  Here is what I have tried so far, with the results:

What song is this? - "Listening for music..."
What song is playing? - "Listening for music..."
What is this song? - "Listening for music..."
What song plays now? - "Listening for music..."
What am I listening to? - "Listening for music..."

What song is playing in my playlist? - web search.
Tell me what song this is. - web search.
What is the song name? - web search.

I think with enough tries we can figure out what voice commands will work.  Please share your results.  :)

EDIT:

Still trying...

Tell me what song is playing. - web search.
Describe this song. - web search.
Identify song. - web search.
play list what song is this. - web search.
Xbox music name song. - web search.
Open playlist. - web search.

I don't think that it's possible anymore.  I wish that it was though!

Comment: Sounds like the sort of thing to suggest via the "Share my feedback about Cortana" link at the bottom of the Cortana screen

Comment: Yes, I agree, but could you try some voice commands of your own to see if you can get it to work?  I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I suspect there is no way to do this. It really wouldn't make sense, since it's much easier to just press the volume button than to press search, ask the question, and wait for Cortana to respond.

Comment: Pressing the volume button or checking the lock screen does work easily.  Thing is since I know that it's possible, I would really like to learn the proper voice command for it.  It might have had something to do with saying "playlist" but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm guessing it's not possible yet.  Probably I asked "my music, what song is this?", and it said something like, "Playing Maze of Stone", which was already playing, so I thought that it worked.

It is obvious now that it can (offline) play a song by saying "Play (song name)" and locate it by the songs metadata.  Also saying "Play album (album name)" works.  I just don't understand why it can find it and say what it's found, and play it, but not just simply say what's now playing.

I hope that they will implement this feature soon, since apparently offline it can decipher what song "to play" and say it aloud.  Seems logical you could say, "What song is this?", and have it read aloud the metadata for the song name.

Answer (score -1):

To find out which song is playing with Cortana
1. Press the **Search** button to got Cortana, then tap the **Music search** icon.
2. Cortana will begin listening. If she can identify the song, it will appear on the screen with the album cover, song title, album and artist. You can tap it to see it in **Xbox Music**.

Cortana also saves the search for you in case you want to come back to it later. YOu can see the songs in **Cortana's Notebook** > **Music searches**. Tap any song to go to its page in **Xbox Music**.

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score -4):

Hope you are getting it wrong. 
You can instruct Cortana to perform a specific task like " Open Bing Search " something like that. 
If you want to find the song by just playing & making the phone listen, you really have a fantastic application called Shazam. I have tested and working perfect.

Just with a press of a button it finds the song by listening to the song.

[Check the blog on shazam here](http://urgeekdad.blogspot.in/2014/12/search-music-by-playing-it-app-of-the-day.html)

Comment: Please re-read the question. He wants to identify the song based on file metadata, not by listening to it and comparing to an online database.